# submit on <input> calls func in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This snippet of code I am using as template:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm date-time-with-arrows" style="width:100%">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="prevDay()"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left "></i></button>
    </span>
    <div id="input" class="input-group input-group-sm nested-group" ng-model="model">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" ng-disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-attr-placeholder="{{configuration.noSelectionLabel}}" />
        <span class="input-group-btn after-date-input">
            <button class="btn btn-default pick-cal" ng-disabled="isDisabled" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <span class="input-group-btn after-date-input">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="nextDay()"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Note functions in tags button prevDay() and nextDay(). When I change date in input and press enter, prevDay() function is called and I have no idea why.

Comment: Because a `<button>` without `type=button` acts as a submit button. And `prevDay` is the first one. When you press enter, this will submit the form.

Comment: Provide more HTML. possibly that template is used inside <form> block, may be inside parent block. I had same problem some time ago. Check your HTML for any broken/used forms. around that template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specificy a `type="button"` for a `<button>`, it will default as a submit button.
The button with function `prevDay()` on it is the first one, which will be used when you hit enter.

Just add `type="button"` to your `<button>`s and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I almost got insane for this just a couple of days ago...

The reason is that angular submits form on click of every button that is not of `type="button"`.

If you change to `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="nextDay()"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>` it should work.